# "Class does not implement interface member" error on class implementing a generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I am getting this error while compiling the code and not able to figure out the exact reason:

> Class does not implement interface member

This is my code:

```
interface IReview<T> where T : Review
{
    IEnumerable<T> Reviews { get; set; }

    void AddReview<T>(T item);  
}

class ReviewCollection : IReview<Review>
{
    IEnumerable<Review> _reviews;

    public IEnumerable<Review> Reviews
    {
        get { return _reviews; }
        set { _reviews = value; }
    }

    public void AddReview(Review item)
    {

    }
}
```

What is the issue with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `AddReview` in the interface is wrong. It should read:

```
void AddReview(T item);
```

The generic type argument `T` is already provided by the class, and you don't want to deviate in your method (in this case). You now changed the meaning of `T` to be a local type parameter, not to use the one available on the class level.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement the generic method:

```
public void AddReview<Review>(Review item)
{    
}
```

Or you should change the signature of the method in your interface:

```
void AddReview(T item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change this method:

```
public void AddReview(Review item)
```

To this:

```
public void AddReview<Review>(Review item)
```